# C# Razor pages BindProperty attribute not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm getting started with my first Razor page and following some examples the `[BindProperty]` attribute is not working...
I'm using MongoDB so I'm not using EntityFramework in my project.

Here is my Model class:

```
public class Student : BaseModel
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}

[Serializable]
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    [JsonProperty(Order = -2)] // appear first
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
    public DateTime CreatedDate;
}
```

Here is my `New.cshtml.cs` code:

```
public class NewModel : PageModel
{
    readonly IStudentsCollection studentsCollection;
    [BindProperty]
    public Student Student { get; set; }


    public NewModel(IStudentsCollection studentsCollection)
    {
        this.studentsCollection = studentsCollection;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        await studentsCollection.InsertAsync(Student);
        return RedirectToPage("Index");
    }
}
```

And finally, here is my `New.cshtml` code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <h4>Add New Student</h4>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.FirstName"></label>
                <input asp-for="Student.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Student.FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Student.LastName"></label>
                <input asp-for="Student.LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Student.LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Upon clicking the "Save" button I'm getting to the `OnPostAsync` method but the `Student` object has all `null` values...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide `set` accessor for your property :

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved it, though I thought not specifying getter and setter shouldn't be a problem (even if the attribute states BindProperty and not BindField).